# Unable to connect to Mysql database on a hosted machine

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using a C# Windows Forms project to use the database on a GoDaddy web host.

This is the error I am getting:
[image]

```
SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=tibia.db.XXXXX.hostedresource.com; Initial Catalog=tibia; User ID=tibia; Password='XXXXX';");
```

When I click the button and debug it, it stops here: `sqlConn.Open();`

```
sqlConn.Open();
SqlCommand sqlComm = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO player (date, name, level, experience) " +
                    "VALUES ('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','" +
                            getPlayerName(Tibia.Handle, (BattleList_Start + Base + (BattleList_Step * playerIndex) + 4)) + "','" + 
                            Convert.ToString(ReadInt32(LvlAdr + Base, 4, Tibia.Handle)) + "','" +
                            Convert.ToString(ReadInt32(XpAdr + Base, 4, Tibia.Handle)) + ")", sqlConn);
sqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery();
sqlConn.Close();
```

Here is the database information provided by GoDaddy.
[image]

All information between the facts and the source are exactly identical and correct.

Does anyone know what I am doing incorrectly?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to be quite honest, what should I be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using MSSQL (Microsoft) classes to access a MySQL database. Of course you are getting an error.

You need to use the [MySql C# Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/dotnet.html). The syntax should be nearly identical. See [this codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL) for some help setting it up. But the short version is: put `MySql` before all your "SQL-related" classes and it should work.

Comment: Okay, I've installed the MySql connection, what am I supposed to do next?  I have checked the Add Reference part, I'm not seeing MySql in there.  Do I need to restart my computer?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it.  I had to browse for the dll file and add it as a reference manually.  The tutorial link you provided did not instruct me to do this, it just expects it to show up automatically...